# Find $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{N}\frac{2r+3}{3^r(r+1)}$

Tags: calculus

I was trying several method but none of them worked particularly.
Also as this is a finite sum I thought of doing mathematical induction too. But it seems like there isn't a general term.
I saw in a book that if you take the infinite series then there is the following relationship$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{2r+3}{3^r(r+1)}=-3\left(-1+2\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\log\left(\frac{27}{8}\right)\right)$$
But I really cannot see how they obtained that either
Appreciate your help

Comment: For that identity, you need to know that $\sum\limits_{r = 1}^\infty \frac{x^r}r = -\log(1 - x)$.

Comment: Since we are going to make duplicates, I edited the title of the linked question to be more explicit.